# c++ opengl drawing only 1 point instead of grid

Tags: c++, opengl, gldrawarrays

I am solving some drawing wrapper for my DLL which is calculating some array. 
In this code I need it to draw, but I dont understand, why when I bind it only once, it draws only 1 point. But when I am binding it(as I know, I should not do that because of memory) every paint event, it's drawing my grid as i expect it to.

Here is initial state of bindData.

```
bool mBindData = true;
```

and then in my draw function:

```
        GLuint vbo;
        if(mBindData){
            mBindData = false;
            glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

            //getting size of my array of vertexes
            int size = this->mModel->GetVboSize() * sizeof(float);


            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, s2, this->mModel->GetVbo(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                        3,                  // size
                        GL_FLOAT,           // type
                        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                        0,                  // stride
                        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                        );
        }
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0,this->mModel->GetVboSize());
```

if there is no

```
if(mBindData){}
```

its working well. But as I said, I am sure its not the way.

I appreciate every advice you can give me.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT1:** My question is, why is it drawing only 1 point instead of NxN grid of points when i bind vbo only once. What am i missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but my guess would be it's because you're generating only one buffer in `glGenBuffers(1, &vbo)`, where you would want NxN points

Comment: I have an array of floats, that creates a grid
float* array = {0.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0,0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}
which is 2x2 grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for a question. I am just stupid and didn't read entire QT component. I had to call update() after paintGL(). It's working now.